# How to resolve the Winusb linking error?

Tags: c++, linker, winusb

I've written a WinUSB project for obtaining data from spectrometer, the code seems to work few weeks ago. In the later stage I tried to link this project with CUDA, after few trials I solved the CUDA linker error. Unfortunately I ended up "**error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol**" in my main program(Winusb project). At first I thought it was because of the .cu files and I decided to remove all the .CU(CUDA)files form the project and still I was keep on getting the same **error(LNK2019**). 
The following is my code for Winusb project (which was working perfectly few weeks back, but now I'm completely lost and needed some help)

Main.cpp

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <cstdio>

LONG __cdecl _tmain(LONG  Argc, LPTSTR * Argv )
{   
FILE *output_file1 = fopen("output_file2.txt", "w");
//FILE *output_file2 = fopen("output_file3.txt", "w");
DEVICE_DATA           deviceData;
HRESULT               hr;
USB_DEVICE_DESCRIPTOR deviceDesc;
BOOL                  bResult;
BOOL                  noDevice;
ULONG                 lengthReceived;
BOOL wrResult = TRUE;
BOOL wr1Result = TRUE;
BOOL RQResult = 0;
UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(Argc);
UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(Argv);


//////////////////////Open device ///////////////
hr = OpenDevice(&deviceData, &noDevice);
if (FAILED(hr)) {
    if (noDevice) {
        printf(_T("Device not connected or driver not installed\n"));
    } else {
       printf(_T("Failed looking for device, HRESULT 0x%x\n"), hr);
    }
    std::getchar();
    return 0;
}

/////////////////////Get descriptor//////////////////
bResult = WinUsb_GetDescriptor(deviceData.WinusbHandle,
                               USB_DEVICE_DESCRIPTOR_TYPE,
                               0,
                               0,
                               (PBYTE) &deviceDesc,
                               sizeof(deviceDesc),
                               &lengthReceived);
   if (FALSE == bResult || lengthReceived != sizeof(deviceDesc)) {

    printf(_T("Error among LastError %d or lengthReceived %d\n"),
           FALSE == bResult ? GetLastError() : 0,
           lengthReceived);
    CloseDevice(&deviceData);
    return 0;
}

bool sResult = FALSE;bool syResult;
bool sResult1 = FALSE;bool syResult1;
//Initialize
UCHAR Intialize[] = {0x01};
ULONG cbISize = strlen((char*)Intialize);
ULONG InSent = 0;
wrResult = WinUsb_WritePipe(deviceData.WinusbHandle, 0x01, Intialize, 1, &InSent, 0);
//Integration time - 700ms
UCHAR Inttime[] = {0x0200100000};
ULONG cbITSize = strlen((char*)Inttime);
ULONG InttimeSent = 0;
wrResult = WinUsb_WritePipe(deviceData.WinusbHandle, 0x01, Inttime, 5, &InttimeSent, 0);
//strobe signal
UCHAR strobe1[] = {0x030001};
ULONG strobeSize1 = strlen((char*)strobe1);
ULONG strobeSent1 = 0;
wr1Result = WinUsb_WritePipe(deviceData.WinusbHandle, 0x01, strobe1, 3, &strobeSent1, 0);
//Request spectra
UCHAR Rqspectra[] = {0x09};
ULONG RqSize = strlen((char*)Rqspectra);
ULONG RqSent = 0;
RQResult = WinUsb_WritePipe(deviceData.WinusbHandle, 0x01, Rqspectra,1, &RqSent, 0);
//Pixel Values
UCHAR szBuffer[15][512];
UCHAR sz1Buffer[1];
UCHAR tBuffer[1];
ULONG tReadx;
ULONG cbReadx[16];
USHORT newbuf[15][512];
short specbu[7860];
for (int i=0;i<16;i++)
{
    if (i<4)
    {
        sResult = WinUsb_ReadPipe(deviceData.WinusbHandle,  0x86, szBuffer[i], 512, &cbReadx[i], 0);
    }
    else if (i>=4 && i<15)
    {
        sResult = WinUsb_ReadPipe(deviceData.WinusbHandle,  0x82, szBuffer[i], 512, &cbReadx[i], 0);
    }
    else if (i = 15)
    {
        syResult = WinUsb_ReadPipe(deviceData.WinusbHandle,  0x82, sz1Buffer, 1, &cbReadx[i], 0);
    }

}
int pon=0;
for (int k=0;k<15;k++)
{
for (int l=0;l<512;l+=2)
{
    newbuf[k][l] = (szBuffer[k][(l+1)]<<8|szBuffer[k][l]);
    specbu[pon]= (szBuffer[k][(l+1)]<<8|szBuffer[k][l]);
    fprintf(output_file1,"%d\t\n",specbu[pon]);
    pon++;

}
}
std::getchar();
CloseDevice(&deviceData);
return 0;
}
```

My Pch.h

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <strsafe.h>
#include <winusb.h>
#include <usb.h>
#include "device.h"
```

My device.h
    #include

```
//
// Device Interface GUID.
// Used by all WinUsb devices that this application talks to.
// Must match "DeviceInterfaceGUIDs" registry value specified in the INF file.
// 390a138c-f867-4538-8fd4-46063b842d2b
//
DEFINE_GUID(GUID_DEVINTERFACE_USBApplication2,
0x390a138c,0xf867,0x4538,0x8f,0xd4,0x46,0x06,0x3b,0x84,0x2d,0x2b);

typedef struct _DEVICE_DATA {

BOOL                    HandlesOpen;
WINUSB_INTERFACE_HANDLE WinusbHandle;
HANDLE                  DeviceHandle;
TCHAR                   DevicePath[MAX_PATH];

}
DEVICE_DATA, *PDEVICE_DATA;
HRESULT
OpenDevice(
_Out_     PDEVICE_DATA DeviceData,
_Out_opt_ PBOOL        FailureDeviceNotFound
);

VOID
CloseDevice(
_Inout_ PDEVICE_DATA DeviceData
);
```

My build log

```
1>------ Build started: Project: USB Application2, Configuration: Win7 Debug Win32 ------
1>  main.cpp
1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "long __stdcall OpenDevice(struct _DEVICE_DATA *,int *)" (?OpenDevice@@YGJPAU_DEVICE_DATA@@PAH@Z) referenced in function _main
1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __stdcall CloseDevice(struct _DEVICE_DATA *)" (?CloseDevice@@YGXPAU_DEVICE_DATA@@@Z) referenced in function _main
1>C:\Users\bel1\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\USB Application2\Win7Debug\USBApplication2.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 2 unresolved externals
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
========== Deploy: 0 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to add source files (.CPP) into your project that are having implementation of following functions:

- `OpenDevice`
- `CloseDevice`

If you are using a third party library, you need to put the relevant `.LIB` file into Linker Input of project settings.

Comment: The device.h has the definition of OpenDevice and CloseDevice(I added the device.h), Also I created the custom INF. The same program was working before, I followed the microsoft link (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff540283(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: But, what about `OpenDevice` functions? From where you grabbed? It must be there in some .CPP file, or in some library. Where is it documented?

Comment: You are right, I removed the device.cpp mistakenly. Thanks